# How to fix IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have written the following code that has a function `model_data` to perform a particular set of tasks. I have to pass the list of `Badges` and the type of category `1 or 2` along with an empty dataframe `data`.

But while running the code I am getting an error. I searched SO for answers but this type of Question was not found.

**CODE**

```
#Model Function

def model_data(badge_list, data):
    
  for key, value in badge_list.items():

    #Check for Post Type
    if (value == 1):
      badge_type = posts.loc[posts.PostTypeId == '1']

    elif (value == 2):
      badge_type = posts.loc[posts.PostTypeId == '2']

    #Obtain required fields from Badge Data 
    badge_type = badge_type[['OwnerUserId', 'Id','Score', 'CreationDate']]
    badge_type.columns = ['UserId', 'Id', 'Score','CreationDate']
 
    Badge = key
    
    #Obtain time when user first obtained Badge
    badge_data = user_badge_dt(Badge)

    #Find the number of posts made before and after 1 week of Badge Attainment
    post_data = post_details(df1 = badge_data, df2 = badge_type)
    post_data.date = pd.to_datetime(post_data.date)
    
    #Calculate APR
    post_data = APR(post_data)    
    
    #Calculate Score
    post_data = score(df = post_data, post_type = badge_type)
    
    #Generate Final Dataframe with Badge Count
    data1 = badge_number(post_data)
    data1 = data1[['1','2','3','date','Score','APR']]
    
    #Append Dataframe
    data = data.append(data1)
  
  return data

#Function Call
questionBadge_list = {'Good Question':1, 'Explainer':2}

data = pd.DataFrame()
badge1_data = model_data(badge_list = questionBadge_list, data = data)
```

**ERROR**

```
IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2
```

**ERROR LINE**
The code line `badge_data = user_badge_dt(Badge)` gives this error so I am adding the complete function.

```
#Function to obtain UserId with the date-time of obtaining given badge for the first time
def user_badge_dt(badge):
  
  #Creating DataFrame to obtain all UserId and date-Time of given badge
  df = badges[['UserId','Date']].loc[badges.Name == badge]
  
  #Obtaining the first date-time of badge attainment
  v = df.groupby("UserId", group_keys=False)['Date'].nsmallest(1)
  v.index = v.index.droplevel(1)

  df['date'] = df['UserId'].map(v)
  df.drop(columns='Date',inplace=True)
  
  #Removing all duplicate values of Users
  df.drop_duplicates(subset='UserId',  inplace=True )

  return df
```

Comment: Which line gave the error?

Comment: @gtomer this line gave the error `badge_data = user_badge_dt(Badge)`. I am adding the function `user_badge_dt` for furthur clarification.

Comment: What's in badge_list.items()?

Comment: @gtomer I have mentioned in the code already that during the function call. The dictionary `questionBadge_list = {'Good Question':1, 'Explainer':2}` has been passed to the parameter `badge_list`.

Comment: @IshanDutta could you print out the ```v.index``` in ```user_badge_dt``` function and share the output? Check the level in index using ```nblevels = v.index.nlevels```